# How does one take derivative of data points

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, numerical-methods

I have a function defined in terms of data points and I need to take the derivative of this function and use it in the Newton Raphson iteration.

The function $f$ below is obtained through a series of definitions -

$$a = \frac{T_{\text{top}} - T_{\text{bottom}}}{\ln P_{\text{top}} - \ln P_{\text{bottom}}} $$

All values are known i.e.  $T_{\text{top}}$, $T_{\text{bottom}}$, $P_{\text{top}}$, $P_{\text{bottom}}$

$$b =  T_{\text{top}} - a \cdot  \ln P_{\text{top}} $$

$$ p \ln =  \ln P_{\text{bottom}} + \frac{\theta - \theta_{\text{bottom}}}{\theta_{\text{top}} - \theta_{\text{bottom}}} * (\ln P_{\text{top}} - \ln P_{\text{bottom}}) $$

pln is the initial guess value for pressure in logarithmic space  for the Newton Raphson iteration.

Here $\theta$, $\theta_{\text{top}}$, $\theta_{\text{bottom}}$ are all known

Finally

$$  ekp = e^{pln}$$

$$  t = a * p ln + b $$

$$ f = t * ekp $$

$$ \frac{df}{dp} = ekp (t -a) $$

So I need to derive the final  expression for Newton Raphson iteration but I would like to have some idea on how to get df/dp since all I have are data points. All I have are discrete measurements of temperature and pressure. Any clue to get to the final derivative will be appreciated as I have to modify a and b to get a different df/dp. Some of these values are constants(such as theta without a subscript) and those will be zero. But what about the others ?

Comment: The equations themselves do not really matter: what matters is what is known and what is unknown. Can you make that more explicit in your case?

Comment: What are you using Newton-Raphson for?  Are you trying to find where the graph of $f$ versus $p$ crosses zero (or some other particular value)?  If so, the hidden question is "How smooth is $f(p)$?", since any attempt to make the derivative sensible will have to assume something about this.  Do you have theoretical or prior information about the smoothness of this function?

Comment: Nobody has a prayer of figuring out what you are talking about with your equations formatted so poorly. Look at [the MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use the knowledge obtained therein to make your equations readable.

Comment: I tried prettying up your question a little. It's still not clear what kinds of things $pln$ and $ekp$ are. Are they single symbols or the product of three variables? It looks like $pln$ is the value of $\ln p$ that you get from interpolating via the independent variable $\theta$. Then $ekp$ is the corresponding value of $p$. I find it hard to avoid reading your equations as $t=t\cdot ekp=\left(a\ln p+b\right)p$ so $$\frac{df}{dp}=a\ln p+b+a=t+a$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume a linear relationship between $\ln p$ and $\theta$ then the two-point formula for the line through $\left(\theta_\text{bottom},\ln P_{\text{bottom}}\right)$ and $\left(\theta_\text{top},\ln P_{\text{top}}\right)$ is
$$\frac{\ln p-\ln P_{\text{bottom}}}{\theta-\theta_\text{bottom}}=\frac{\ln P_{\text{top}}-\ln P_{\text{bottom}}}{\theta_\text{top}-\theta_\text{bottom}}$$
Then
$$\ln p=\ln P_{\text{bottom}}+\frac{\theta-\theta_\text{bottom}}{\theta_\text{top}-\theta_\text{bottom}}\left(\ln P_{\text{top}}-\ln P_{\text{bottom}}\right)$$
Also we assume a linear relationship between $t$ and $\ln p$ so that $t=a\ln p+b$. Knowing $T_{\text{bottom}}=a\ln P_{\text{bottom}}+b$ and $T_{\text{top}}=a\ln P_{\text{top}}+b$ we can solve for $a$ and $b$ to get
$$a=\frac{T_{\text{top}}-T_{\text{bottom}}}{\ln P_{\text{top}}-\ln P_{\text{bottom}}}$$
and
$$b=T_{\text{top}}-a\ln P_{\text{top}}$$
Then if we define
$$f=te^{\ln p}=tp=\left(a\ln p+b\right)p$$
We have
$$\frac{df}{dp}=a+a\ln p+b=t+a$$